# How to stop video autoplay (Adobe Flash Videos) in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash

I added the extension Flashcontrol version 9.2.415 to stop Flash video autoplay at sites like this one:
http://www.mediaite.com/online/you-dont-actually-operate-in-facts-jose-antonio-vargas-and-tucker-carlson-clash/

It didn't work.

Would someone be so kind as to tell me which setting makes the difference? I can't get it to work on either my laptop or my desktop -- both running Windows 10 and Flash Version 24,0,0,194.

I am seeing links with Google search to instructions that don't seem to apply, which is why I added version numbers. For example, it was suggested to scroll down in the Content Settings and make a change to Plug-ins 3 radio buttons. But that must be an old version of Chrome, because there is no Plug-ins with 3 radio buttons.

Google Chrome   55.0.2883.87 (Official Build) m (32-bit)
Flash   24.0.0.194

Comment: If you are talking about YouTube, they use HTML5 on most things, so the answer below is the way to go.

Comment: As for Flash itself, simply uninstall Adobe Flash and let Chrome handle it.  Fewer bugs that way.

Comment: TY SDsolar. 
Just 2 b clear I was referring to Flash videos only and the need to keep Flash installed to use with Firefox & Chrome. 
Here's the link to the autoplay video (one of many): 
http://www.mediaite.com/online/you-dont-actually-operate-in-facts-jose-antonio-vargas-and-tucker-carlson-clash/

Comment: The video didn't autoplay for me, I have vanilla Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The videos on this site (and a lot of others nowadays) are not flash based player but rather HTML5 video players. (see, for instance, this player's details on its site: [www.jwplayer.com](http://www.jwplayer.com))

To disable autoplay for them you can install the Chrome extension [**Disable HTML5 Autoplay**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-html5-autoplay/efdhoaajjjgckpbkoglidkeendpkolai?hl=en). Just install it, click on it and press **Disable autoplay**

[image]

Comment: I use this and it works for Youtube.